# d3 and path lines, driving me crazy

Tags: svg, d3.js

I've been tracing my code and comparing notes between my own code and some sample code

I'm working from this sample code: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/bundle.html

My source example is here: http://www.nogumallowed.com/test5.php

My problem is the path lines. They work, they connect, but I love in the source how the lines have more seemingly random curves to them. I can'y figure out how to recreate that. Mine all flow incredibly well, but look rather plain in comparison.

Can anyone offer any insights? I've been coming back to this for a few days, and haven't figured it out yet. The documentation hasn't tipped me in the right direction yet either.

I'm just scratching the surface of "comfortable with D3", but there's still A LOT for me to learn on it before I give myself a D3 Jedi.

Comment: This is probably because you don't really have any bundles. That is, your lines don't bunch together as nicely because you don't really have that many.

Comment: I pruned that one down for easy viewing, here's a complete chart, http://www.nogumallowed.com/test4.php - very full, but still the bland lines.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your clustering code (if you have any) is working very well.  The subjects should be clustered together into related groups, but it doesn't appear like yours are.  For instance, your node "John Sly" is connected to almost very other node except the few on either side of it.  It seems to me that those nine or so highly connected nodes should be distributed around the circle, not bunched next to each other.